# Install Internet explorer on Server 2019 Standard

Tags: windows-server-2019, internet-explorer

I am running server2019 standard and Remote Desktop services.  I have installed Quickbooks enterprise 2021 which requires IE 11.  Someone uninstalled IE11 from the server and now I cant seem to put it back. I am not sure how to reinstall IE11 on server 2019.  I have read that it is supported, but cant seem to find how to install it.  I did find some articles on installing the FOD, but that is for Core not standard (GUI) version.  Any suggestion on installing IE on server 2019 standard?

Answer (score 3):

You can install or uninstall IE from Settings -> Apps -> Manage optional features:

[image]

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/browsers/disable-internet-explorer-windows.